# auditctl reports "File system watches not supported" on a very old system

Tags: kernel, audit

When I run auditctl -l I got:

```
# auditctl -l
No rules
File system watches not supported
```

And I've already have AUDITSYSCALL enable in kernel,

```
# zgrep AUDIT /proc/config.gz
CONFIG_AUDIT_ARCH=y
CONFIG_AUDIT=y
CONFIG_AUDITSYSCALL=y
CONFIG_AUDIT_TREE=y
```

So what could be wrong here? I'm using `auditctl version 1.0.12` with kernel 2.6.32

Answer (score 0):

First understand how the audit system works and how to add syscall rules using `auditctl`.

This [opensuse doc page](http://doc.opensuse.org/products/draft/SLES/SLES-security_sd_draft/cha.audit.comp.html) might be helpful.

Comment: It would not be the first time that SuSE documentation was no longer accessible, your link would be invalidated and your answer unhelpful. You should copy the relevant material here, and use the link as a pointer to more detailed (but inessential) information as well as for giving credit.